# Show current week items is views

Tags: views

I want to create a view which shows all items of the current week based on the publication date.
The week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday. 
I tried the relative date filter in the Views module with 'between last Sunday and this Saturday'
This works. But on Sunday, it shows all the items of the past week, so, on Sunday, the view is not correct.
Could anyone help me with an solution?

Answer (score 2):

The key is using **-1 second** So

1. first solution: Use this values

   **next sunday - 1 week**

   and

   **next sunday  - 1 second**
2. Second solution  based on you told on question :

   **last sunday**
     and
     **this sunday - 1 second**